# Binary Tree Transformation

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, transformation

```
        1                                 5 
    /       \                             |
   2         3            -->             2
 /  \       / \                         /   \
4    5     6   7                       1     4
                                       |
                                       3
                                     /   \
                                    6     7
```

Let say you have a binary tree like the one on the left and try to convert it to the one on the right.

What it does is that it bumps 'any' single leaf node of the binary tree -- this case '5' -- which makes the leaf node a new root node. The original root node (and it's children) -- this case '1' and its children -- takes up the then leaf node space.

What's would be the general algorithm for this?

Thank you for help.

Comment: A [tree rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_rotation), perhaps? At least, some modified form thereof.

Answer (score 1):

That depends pretty much on the structure supporting the binary tree (for example, if you store the parent of each node or not, and so on). Supposing you store the value of the node and the left and right descendants (the most basic information), the problem is reduced to "reverse" all the arcs from the current root down to the node that will become the new root. Something like this, I guess, in Java-style pseudo-code:

```
void rev(Node u, Node v) {
  // make v point back to u
  if (v.left == null) v.left = u;
  else v.right = u;
  // free edge from u to link up
  if (u.left == v) u.left = null;
  else u.right = null;
}

boolean reroot(Node root, Node parent, Node newRoot) { // assumes that newRoot is a leaf
  if (root != null)
    if (root == newRoot) {
      rev(root, parent);
      return true;
    } else {
      if (reroot(root.left, root) || reroot(root.right, root)) {
        rev(root, parent);
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Nevertheless, I didn't test the code above.

EDIT: the initial call would be reroot(currentRoot, null, newRoot);

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts: starting from a node, we add its parent node and another unexplored branch to the new tree as the new branches, and then we recursively build the new tree by iterating back through the original tree till its root.

a python style pseudo-code would be like this:

```
NewTree=Node
NoLongerChildNode=NULL
while (Node!=root):
    NewTree.attach(Node.anotherchild(NoLongerChildNode))
    NewTree=NewTree.attach(Node.parent)
    NoLongerChildNode=Node
    Node=Node.parent
NewTree.attach(Node.anotherchild(NoLongerChildNode))
```